# Insert input Data And Compare Data Available Or not in database

Tags: php, laravel-5

Insert input Data  And Compare Data Available Or not in the database

```
$health         = $request->input('health');
$tran           = $request->input('transportation');
$smoke          = $request->input('smoke');
$trial =   Trial::select(array('health' => $health, 'transportation' => $tran,'smoke' => $smoke));
//dd($trial);
if(!isset($trial)){
    return view('home');
}   else{
    return view('patient-home.trialresult',compact('health','tran','smoke'));
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `select` with `where` followed by `get()` in the end

Answer (score 0):

Some changes in your query,

```
$trial =   Trial::where(array('health' => $health, 'transportation' => $tran,'smoke' => $smoke))->get();
```

should work.

Replaced `where` to `select` and followed by `->get()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `select` to `where` and append `->get()` at the end

```
$trial = Trial::where([
    ['health', '=', $health],
    ['transportation', '=', $tran,
    ['smoke', '=', $smoke]
])->get();
```

OR

```
$trial = Trial::where('health', $health)
    ->where('transportation', $tran)
    ->where('smoke', $smoke)
    ->get();
```

**Note:** if you are passing an array to where, it has to be a 2D array else you use a fluent chaining of `where`'s

from [laravel doc 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$trialExists = Trial::where('health', $health) ->where('transportation', $tran) ->where('smoke', $smoke) ->exists();
```

And then check if it exists like this:

```
if($trialExists){ return view('home'); } else{ return view('patient-home.trialresult',compact('health','tran','smoke')); }
```

This is a cleaner way since you only want to check it's existence.